# Django mlbgame object list of lists

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am new to Python, and I know a little big of Java, so I kind of know objects.Now, in python I am using mlbgame to get the schedule of one team. I am using games(years, months=None, days=None, home=None, away=None).

Here is my view

```
def baseball(request):
    angels_game = mlbgame.games(2017, home='Angels', away='Angels')
    return render(request, 'home/baseball.html', {'games1': games1, 'angels_game': angels_game})
```

Now here is my template

```
<h1>Anaheim Angels Games</h1>
    {% for anaheim in angels_game %}
        <p>{{ anaheim }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

This is what I get in my page

Anaheim Angels Games

```
[<mlbgame.game.GameScoreboard object at 0x7f04f2f0ac50>]

[<mlbgame.game.GameScoreboard object at 0x7f04f31f5978>]

[<mlbgame.game.GameScoreboard object at 0x7f04f2ef22e8>]

[<mlbgame.game.GameScoreboard object at 0x7f04f1e9b048>]
```

I understand, I am getting the object there, but I do know how to use that object, like I would do in Java using the toString() method.

Can anybody direct me on the right path here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. I found the answer after trying your ideas.

It is as Sanca Kembang suggested, it was in the view the problem. There is a function called combine_games that takes a object. Here is the code

```
def baseball(request):
    angels_game = mlbgame.games(2017, home='Angels', away='Angels')
    games = mlbgame.combine_games(angels_game)
    return render(request, 'home/baseball.html', {'games': games})
```

Everything else remained the same, and I got what I wanted.

```
Brewers (0) at Angels (0)

Angels (0) at Athletics (0)

Padres (0) at Angels (0)

Angels (0) at Cubs (0) ....
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think you need to overwrite your list at the backend to get the output for your list iterator, for example: `[ angle.get_score() for angle in angels_game ]`. Because, the result of your iteration is class of `GameScoreboard`, it doesn't complete enough..

Here i found the function [`nice_score()`](https://github.com/zachpanz88/mlbgame/blob/master/mlbgame/game.py#L158) inside class of `GameScoreboard`.

**So, perhaps you should try with this one:**

```
def baseball(request):
    angels_game = mlbgame.games(2017, home='Angels', away='Angels')
    angels_game_list = [ angle.nice_score() for angle in angels_game ]

    return render(request, 'home/baseball.html', 
        {.... 'angels_game': angels_game_list}
    )
```

Comment: Thank you, but that still gives me an error, something like the object does not have nice_score attribute.

Comment: please try `print (dir(angels_game))` what the output of it?